# Audit Trail in Apex application using SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

My Apex application has to capture users on when they accessed the application and what they queried within the application. 
Since this is a Read-only application the application need not capture insert, update or delete changes.

Could this be done with Apex? If you could explain on how this can be done, it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. I can only show directions for work:

- to audit logging you can create custom authentication scheme and write login attempts within an authentication function.
- to audit actions you can use processes. A process with type `On Load - Before Header` can be used for logging visited pages, a process with type `On Submit` - for logging actions.

**Edit**
I've just found this chapter in APEX documentation: [Creating Custom Activity Reports Using APEX_ACTIVITY_LOG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/advnc_act_log.htm#HTMDB13003). As I can understand, it is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Apex hence the confusion. From your answer, it is clear to me that I need to audit actions and use On Submit for the users rather than login attempts.

Comment: I have one more thing to clarify - the link provided tells me the column - `ir_search` works only for interactive search reports. My application has standard reports and data forms from which I need to know which user accessed and what did they query in the form fields. Is this still possible?